# Minimum Vertex Cover and Set Inclusion

Tags: graph-theory

Let $H \subseteq G$ be graphs. Is it true that for any minimum vertex cover $V$ of $G$, there exists some $U \subseteq V$ or $U \cap V = \emptyset$ such that $U$ is a minimum vertex cover of $H$?

Comment: What if $H\cap V$ is empty?

Comment: In that case $H$ should have no edges, since if there is an edge between any two vertices of $H$, then at least one of the vertices should be in $V$. Thus, every vertex is isolated, and we can let $U = \emptyset \subset V$ to get a vertex cover.